# Proving that $f: SO(n) \to S^{n-1}$ is regular map.

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$
I have problem with following task:

Let $f: SO(n) \to S^{n-1}$ will be a function that takes first column of the matrix. Proof that $f$ is regular in every point $M \in SO(n)$.

So I know that elements from $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ can be treated as elements from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and that $f$ is projection on first $n$ coordinates. So I need to construct Jacobi matrix $J_f$ and proof that $df$ is epimorphism (equivalently that $\rank J_f = n-1$). Moreover $SO(n)$ is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$-dimensional space so $J_f$ will be matrix $n \times \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. But here I don't know how to formally justify regularity of $f$. First columns do not have to be orthogonal to one another and I don't know if I will always find $n-1$ lineary independent columns. I would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: To be precise, you do not need to calculate $J_f$. You need only to show that the differential $df$ is surjective. Hint: for each $A\in SO(n)$, the span of the remaining $n-1$ column is exactly $T_{f(A)} \mathbb S^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f$ is of constant rank, as $f(g h)= g.f(h)$ where $g$ is a diffeormorphism (the linear map $g$. As it is surjective it must be of maximal rank everywhere.  You can alos check that its derivative near he origin is the map $A_n\to R^{n}$ which maps an antisymmetric matrix to its first column is onto the space of vectors $\perp$ to $(1,0,..0)$.

Comment: Could you explain the first equivalence - $f(gh) = gf(h)$ once again ?

Comment: The first column of the matrix $g$ is $g.e_1$, if $e_1$ is the vector $(1,0..,0)$. Thus $f( gh)= g.f(h)$